# Return throwing ternary operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, ternary-operator, throw

Reading the documentation of the ternary operator, I've realized that there are two special cases that I've never used:

- you can use it with functions that return void : `bool ? void : void`
- you can throw inside a ternary operator

So is the following valid, completely defined, and oftenly used (assuming that this is a class member, and the class owns a `Type _data[Size]`) ?

```
Type& at(const unsigned int i) 
{
    return (i < Size) ? (_data[i]) : (throw std::out_of_range("ERROR"));
}
```

Comment: (also it may help you to know that this operator is known as the "conditional operator". It's only "ternary" in the same way that `+` is binary, etc.)

Comment: `throw` in a condition operator is often used in C++11 `constexpr` programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is valid and well-defined (assuming suitable definitions of `Size` and `_data`). As to "oftenly used" - I personally have never seen such a construct before, for what it's worth.

Comment: +1 Valid, well-defined, but pretty much never used. If you wanna throw, use a good old `if` for readability. It's just a style issue though, so YMMV. Just don't be surprised if everybody and their dog yells at you when they see this construct.